# Telegram бот реализация обратной связи/отзывов (Python, Aiogram)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, бот

Проблема простая, но реализовать не так просто. Есть телеграм бот, который просто отвечает на нажатия инлайн кнопок от пользователя. Нужно реализовать инлайн кнопку обратной связи.(отзыв о работе бота, предложения, жалобы) Пользователь нажимает на нее - может написать только текст, который потом отправляется по id админу. Проблема в том, что если пользователь не нажал на кнопку "Оставить отзыв", то ему выдает ответ типа "я вас не понимаю, пользуйтесь кнопками", а сообщение, которое отправил пользователь удаляется,  последущие сообщения, стикеры, видео и тд от пользователя просто удаляются, а ответ "я вас не понимаю, пользуйтесь кнопками" остается висеть один, не дублируясь на каждое мусорное сообщение от пользователя.
Если кнопка нажата, у пользователя появляется возможность написать текст, текст отправляется админу, ответ от бота пользователю "Спасибо за отзыв". Причем отзыв пользователь может писать только текстом, на видео, стикеры и тд, ответ типа "отзывы принимаются только в текстовом формате"
Пробовал реализовать через fsm, однако не работало так, как задумано, пользователь просто не мог написать сообщение, даже при нажатой кнопке "Оставить отзыв"

```
from aiogram import *
from aiogram.types import *
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup

bot = Bot(token="123456")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)


class FeedbackState(StatesGroup):
    waiting_for_feedback = State()


action_menuKB = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2) \
    .add(InlineKeyboardButton("Оставить отзыв ", callback_data="feedback"))


@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == "feedback")
async def show_feedback_message(cbq: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(cbq.id)

    await cbq.message.answer("Ваш отзыв будет передан администратору. Введите пожалуйста сообщение: ")

    await FeedbackState.waiting_for_feedback.set()

    await state.update_data(expecting_feedback=True)


@dp.message_handler(state=FeedbackState.waiting_for_feedback, content_types=ContentTypes.TEXT)
async def handle_feedback_message(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()
    if "expecting_feedback" in data and data["expecting_feedback"]:
        admin_user_id = 123456

        user_id = message.from_user.id
        feedback_message = message.text

        await bot.send_message(admin_user_id, f"Новый отзыв от {user_id}:\n{feedback_message}")
        await message.answer("Спасибо за отзыв! Ваше сообщение было передано администратору.")

        await state.finish()

        await state.update_data(expecting_feedback=False)
    else:
        await message.delete()
        await message.answer("Я не понимаю вашего сообщения "
                             "\nПожалуйста, используйте кнопки.",
                             reply_markup=action_menuKB)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    from aiogram import executor

    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Хочу понять иду ли по правильному пути, что стоит добавить, лучший ли вариант использовать стэйты, и почему не работает момент отличия включенной кнопки от случайного "мусорного текста", когда пользователь не хотел оставлять обратную связь.

Благодарю

Comment: собственно от сообщества что вы ожидаете? что вам напишут готового бота? ни одного вопроса вы не задали, не показали свой код. Звучит как ТЗ, а с таким, будьте добры, на любую фриланс-биржу

Comment: @ZxNuClear благодарю, попытался скорректировать вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял всю вашу задумку, то ваш бот должен придерживаться следующих правил:

1. Чтобы бот вне состояния сообщал, что нужно воспользоваться кнопкой
2. Во время запроса сообщения от пользователя бот игнорировал любой контент, кроме текстового, подсказывая об этом пользователю
3. Была возможность отменить состояние запроса обратной связи

если все так, то данную задумку я бы реализовал вот так:

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.dispatcher import FSMContext
from aiogram.dispatcher.filters.state import State, StatesGroup
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup, InlineKeyboardButton, CallbackQuery, Message
from aiogram.utils import executor

bot = Bot(token="TOKEN")
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)
ADMIN_ID = '' # ID администратора


class FeedbackState(StatesGroup):
    waiting_for_feedback = State()


action_menuKB = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2) \
    .add(InlineKeyboardButton("Оставить отзыв ", callback_data="feedback"))

cancel_KB = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2) \
    .add(InlineKeyboardButton("Не хочу оставлять отзыв ", callback_data="cancel_feedback"))


@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: Message):
    await message.answer('Приветствую! Для того, чтобы оставить отзыв нажмите кнопку снизу', reply_markup=action_menuKB)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text="feedback")
async def show_feedback_message(call: CallbackQuery):
    await call.message.answer("Ваш отзыв будет передан администратору. Введите пожалуйста сообщение: ")
    await FeedbackState.waiting_for_feedback.set()


@dp.message_handler(state=FeedbackState.waiting_for_feedback)
async def handle_feedback_message(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.send_message(ADMIN_ID, f"Новый отзыв от {message.from_user.id}:\n{message.text}")
    await message.answer("Спасибо за отзыв! Ваше сообщение было передано администратору.")
    await state.finish()


@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'document', 'photo', 'video', 'video_note', 'sticker', 'voice'])
async def answer_without_kb(message: Message):
    await message.delete()
    await message.answer("Я не понимаю вашего сообщения "
                         "\nПожалуйста, используйте кнопки.",
                         reply_markup=action_menuKB)


@dp.callback_query_handler(state='*', text="cancel_feedback")
async def cancel_feedback(call: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await call.message.answer('Отменено! Если все же захотите оставить отзыв - отправьте команду /start')
    await state.finish()


@dp.message_handler(state='*', content_types=['document', 'photo', 'video', 'video_note', 'sticker', 'voice'])
async def answer_on_media(message: Message):
    await message.answer("Я принимаю только текстовые сообщения", reply_markup=cancel_KB)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

имейте ввиду, что последние три хэндлера должны располагаться в самом низу

Comment: Премного благодарен, корректирую под себя, и это решает мою проблему.